# What would be a more efficient way of storing variables?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, int, constexpr

I am working on a music program that calls notes from the chromatic scale based on intervals. These interval variables (h - half step, w - whole step and wh -whole and a half step) will be used for determining scale incriments (Major = WWHWWWH) and will later be used to measure interval lengths across a vector of strings to potentially output measurements like "3 Whole Steps and a Half Step".

I'm wondering what would be the more efficient way to store the simple variables, as I would eventually like to make a cellphone app out of it and want it to be as easy on the battery/memory as possible. . And I am still learning. Here are my thoughts:

```
int H = 1;
int W = 2;
int WH = 3;
Int Fiv = 5;
Int Sev = 7;
```

or

```
int H = 1;  
int W = H+H;  
int WH = W + H; 
int Fiv = WH+W; 
int Sev = Fiv + W;

Int H = 1; int W = H*2; int WH = W+H; etc..
```

I'm primarily interested in how the differentiation of initialization will effect both memory and performance if at all?

I know I shouldn't have everything in main, but this is a work in progress, and I am obviously new to programming - so please look past the layout .. here is the code it's presently being used in..

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector> 
#include <map>

const std::vector<std::string> st_sharps{"C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","A#","B" };
const std::vector<std::string> st_flats{"C","Db","D","Eb","E","F","Gb","G","Ab","A","Bb","B" };

struct steps{ int maj = 0; int min = 0;} step;
constexpr int H = 1;
constexpr int W = 2;
constexpr int Tre = 3;
constexpr int Fif = 5;
constexpr int Sev = 7;
const int size = st_flats.size();
const std::vector<int> Major = { W, W, H, W, W, W, H };

struct circle{
std::stringstream sharp;
std::stringstream flat;
std::stringstream minor;
std::stringstream dimin; };

struct scales{
circle fifths;
std::stringstream maj;
std::stringstream min; } scale;

int main(){
    //Circle of Fifths
   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        int five = j * Sev;
        scale.fifths.sharp << st_sharps[five % size] << " ";        
        scale.fifths.flat << st_flats[five % size] << " ";
        scale.fifths.minor << st_sharps[((size - Tre) + five) %  size] << " ";
        scale.fifths.dimin << st_sharps[((size - H) + five) % size] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "Circle of Fifths:\n";
    std::cout << "Major >> Relative Minor >> Diminished " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Maj: " << scale.fifths.sharp.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Min: " << scale.fifths.minor.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dim: " << scale.fifths.dimin.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nflats: " << scale.fifths.flat.str() << "\n" << std::endl;

    //Major and Minor Scales
    for (int i = 0; i < Major.size(); i++) {
        scale.maj << st_sharps[step.maj] << " ";
        scale.min << st_flats[((size - Tre) + step.min) % size] << " ";
        step.maj += Major[i];
        step.min += Major[(i + Fif) % Major.size()];
    }
    std::cout << "C Major:\n" << scale.maj.str() << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A Minor:\n" << scale.min.str() << "\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to study C++ operators a little bit more, first, before contemplating these weighty matters, because your two alternative versions of the same code are not equivalent, and produce different results. `H`, `W`, and `WH` will have different values, in the two alternative versions.

Comment: If you're going to use `constexpr` then you should in your example. You shouldn't spam a million not necessary tags, and you should try to ask a question that can be answered with facts and not only opinions. If you had used constexpr you'd come to a very quick conclusion that @SamVarshavchik pointed out.

Comment: The first is clear, the second has a different meaning as `int` post increment mutates it's operand, i've only ever seen the third used to easily define mathematical constants i.e. `constexpr double tau = pi + pi;`

Comment: H is Half. W is Whole. WH is Whole and a Half for musical intervals.. not Height and Width like some would probably think.. I'm on mobile so I haven't had the time to test these out but I'm wondering what's the most efficient for memory management. All of these answers are the exact reason why I was asking minus ridicule.

Comment: @RichardChristopher your question makes no sense. In your examples, there's no difference in _storage_ as your question asks, nor do your examples illustrate what you're trying to do. If you edit your question to include an example or desired usage with `constexpr` and usage with `vector` and `map`, then you can hope to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Just updated the op

Comment: @RichardChristopher I'm see but I'm still very confused. What effect should `H` have over `W`? How *in code* do you want to use `H`, `W` and `WH`? As member variables? As template parameters? As something like an `enum`? As sizes of a `vector` or other container? Please include a concrete code example of your end goal that illustrates what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It'll eventually replace the numbers in a map of strings, vectors<int> {"Harmonic",    { 0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12 }},... I'm still new. I'm sure this wouldn't work.. Could be Harmonic { +=W, +=H, +=W, +=W, +=H, +=WH +=H } .. something like that. I'm still new.

Comment: @RichardChristopher I think what you want is really simple if you just put the logic somewhere else. Given some vector of _differences_ like `{ 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1 }` or `{W, H, W, W, H, WH, H}` (from your example), you can simply calculate a running sum in a loop to generate a new vector like `{0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 1}`.

Comment: I edited my question. Can this be unheld and my account unsuspended?

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose a version that expresses "'W' is the double of 'H'" the best way. My preferred way would therefore be:

```
constexpr int H = 1;
constexpr int W = 2*H;
constexpr int WH = W+H;
```

Note that your version `int W = H++` is not what you probably intend, since `H++` is not equal to `H+1`; it is actually equal to `int W = H; H = H + 1`.

Comment: It'll eventually replace the numbers in a map of strings, vectors<int> {"Harmonic",    { 0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12 }},... I'm still new. I'm sure this wouldn't work.. Could be Harmonic { +=W, +=H, +=W, +=W, +=H, +=WH +=H } .. something like that. I'm still new.

Comment: רועי אבידן - what would that look like?

Comment: Can this be unheld?

Comment: @RichardChristopher You have now 2 reopen votes, 3 another and you've won. If it doesn't happen in a day, ping me.